# Pyinstaller "Failed to script execute main" problem

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Edit: Python 3.7.4, Windows 10

Edit2: I found the reason for the error. output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "myMain.py", line 2, in <module>
 File "c:\users\faruk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site- 
packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
 File "site-packages\PyQt5\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
 File "site-packages\PyQt5\__init__.py", line 33, in find_qt
ImportError: unable to find Qt5Core.dll on PATH
[13936] Failed to execute script myMain
```

Here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56962128/9377945

I am trying to convert my py files to exe with pyinstaller.

My sample code is here:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize    

class HelloWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(640, 480))    
        self.setWindowTitle("Hello world") 

        centralWidget = QWidget(self)          
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)   

        gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)     
        centralWidget.setLayout(gridLayout)  

        title = QLabel("Hello World", self) 
        title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) 
        gridLayout.addWidget(title, 0, 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = HelloWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

I used this code for convert:

```
pyinstaller main.py --noconsole
```

When I tried to run exe file, I got 'Failed to execute script main' error.

Comment: Try this: `pyinstaller -c -F main.py`
Report the result.

Comment: I tried and cmd opened and closed. I added extra one parameter -w and got same error.

Comment: Try changing the module name, for example to `myMain.py` and run `pyinstaller -c -F myMain.py` again.
Report the result.

Comment: @ImCoder What version of PyQt5 and PyInstaller do you use?

Comment: pyinstaller version 3.5

Comment: @S.Nick I got some warnings and same error. Warnings: 8857 WARNING: One binary added with two internal names.
8859 WARNING: ('libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\users\\faruk\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
8860 WARNING: was placed previously at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove pyinstaller and PyQt5 and then install them with using **pip3**

```
pip3 install pyinstaller   
pip3 install PyQt5
```

Comment: I am using windows 10 doesn't matter pip or pip3. I tried to reinstall them

Comment: @ImCoder why? look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41501815/8767186

Comment: nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

have you installed those packages? if you're using an IDE for coding, you have to install your packages in your system too

Comment: I am using Vscode, virtualenv and my packages(only pyqt5) installed. Code works nice before convert.

Comment: are you using windows? you must install pyqt5 in your windows system too. (command prompt)

Comment: I am using windows. pyqt5 only installed in virtualenv. I will try it

Comment: Nothing changed. Same error.